# Visual studio code: ability to work with two Python repository in one workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

**Intro**:

In **PyCharm**, there is ability to open several Git repositories and specify dependencies between them, so that you can import packages from one repository into another repository and use methods from them with IntelliSense (auto-completion - when you can see methods for a given object).

In **Visual Studio Code**, there is ability to add several git repositories to one workspace, but auto completion for object/methods works only in the current repository:

Say, I have **abcd.py** in **Repo 1** and **fgh**.py in **Repo 2**, and I import a class from fgh.py to abcd.py. In this scheme, when I edit **abcd.py**, auto completion works only for objects/methods in classes from Repo 1, not for objects/methods in a class from Repo 2.

**Question**:

Is it somehow possible to configure Visual Studio Code in such a way that auto completion works in the case described above - like it works in PyCharm?

Thank you.

I googled it, but didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take to achieve this.

### 1. Specify additional import paths in VS Code

You can modify the [language server settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_pylance-language-server) to include the path where `fgh.py` is found.

In VS Code's settings, add its path to the `python.analysis.include` option.

### 2. Install the dependency as an editable package with Pip

This is similar to installing a package normally, but the location of it is set to the original location, rather than creating a copy of it (meaning edits are seen in any code using the package). See the documentation [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html).

`pip install -e /path/to/the/library`

This should give VS Code enough information to allow it to provide intellisense, and is editor-independent (so would work in all projects).

### 3. Open VS Code to a parent folder so the import relationship can be determined

For example, if your directory structure is

- `/my/project/`

  - `lib_1`

    - `fgh.py`
  - `lib_2`

    - `abcd.py`

You could potentially open up `/my/project` and VS Code should hopefully spot the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Miguell! I will try to use something like that. I forgot to mention that my repositories are remote one, and I connect to them from VS Code via SSH. So it brings some more difficulties, but I try to cope with it using your suggestions.